# Call an event on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I develop **extensions** which adds js code to a third-party service and automatically fills out a form for a client.

I need to call a click on a specific element on the site, I tried all the options for triggering events and did not find a solution. Maybe someone knows what other options for calling **click**?

The site is implemented on **knockoutjs** and here is the html component of this element (Maybe it will be useful)

```
<div role="treeitem" class="fxc-dropdown-option msportalfx-tooltip-overflow fxs-portal-hover" data-bind="&quot;attr&quot;:{&quot;aria-selected&quot;:ko.unwrap($disabled) ? null : $ctl._isSelected($data.value).toString(),&quot;id&quot;:$ctl._assignId(),&quot;aria-disabled&quot;:$disabled,&quot;aria-label&quot;:ko.unwrap($data.ariaLabel) || null},&quot;css&quot;:{&quot;fxc-dropdown-option-disabled&quot;:$disabled,&quot;fxs-portal-hover&quot;:!ko.unwrap($disabled),&quot;fxs-portal-selected&quot;:$ctl._isSelected($data.value)}" aria-selected="false" id="">
```

Also, those functions that I used and they did not help

```
selector.click();
$(selector).click();
$(selector).change();
$(selector).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: how did you get `temp` variable?

Comment: What is temp here, You need to use a selector to trigger click event.

Comment: By `temp` I meant `selector`

Comment: @AntonMudrak this does not help. What is your selector ?

Comment: if you have jquery included, this should work: `$('.fxc-dropdown-option').click();`

Comment: @Nicolas I work through "store as global variable chrome" in the console and therefore I do not specify the selector.

Comment: @Qubis741 This is not a selector, it is checked and does not work like that

Comment: if the element is generated dynamically you need to use `$(selector).find(element).trigger("click")` where selector is a parent element

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('NAME').dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```